# Objective-C dynamic view creation with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, uiview, autolayout

Have been searching and can't find any solutions.

I have a view that will contain a certain amount of subviews upon initialization parameters.

I want to layout these subviews using autolayout programmatically.

Normally, I'd use:

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_view1, _view2);
```

but this requires that my view hold a property for each view, and I don't know how many I'll need until runtime...

With no luck, I am aiming for something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [self.rows intValue]; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < [self.steps intValue]; j++) {
            LED *led = [[LED alloc] init];
            [self.leds addEntriesFromDictionary:@{[NSString stringWithFormat:@"led%d_%d", i, j]:led}];
        }
    }
    for(LED *led in self.leds) {
        [self addSubview:led];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < [self.rows intValue]; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < [self.steps intValue]; j++) {
            NSString *horizontalConstraint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"|-%d-[led%d_%d]", (LED_WIDTH*j), i, j];
            NSString *verticalConstraint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-%d-[led%d_%d]", (LED_HEIGHT*i), i, j];
            [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:horizontalConstraint options:0 metrics:nil views:self.leds]];
            [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:verticalConstraint options:0 metrics:nil views:self.leds]];
        }
    }
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong or a better method please do Share and Help!!

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts are how you are creating constraints.  If you must use the visual format language, it's cleaner to use the metrics dictionary.  The metrics dictionary lets you use variables for things like distance instead of using NSStringWithFormat.  For example

```
     NSNumber *distanceFromLeft = @(LED_WIDTH*j);
    id led = ....;
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-distanceFromLeft-[led]" options:0 metrics:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(distanceFromLeft) views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(led)]];
```

I know that's not plug and play code but I hope it makes sense.

If it were me I would probably grab each view individually and use the constraintWithItem method instead.  It's a little more verbose and will take several more lines but It will look cleaner and probably be more readable than the visual format string with all the substitutions you have going on.  You also don't need to create and maintain the views dictionary.  Since your actually only creating a constraint to pin your views x and y distance from the left and top of the superview the constraints are very simple

```
    id view1 = //pull the view from your array, or run this when you create the view itself.
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                         constraintWithItem:view1
                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                         toItem:self
                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                         multiplier:1
                         constant:LED_WIDTH*j]];

    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                         constraintWithItem:view1
                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                         toItem:self
                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                         multiplier:1
                         constant:LED_WIDTH*i]];
```

I wonder if just setting the frames wouldn't just be easier, is there a reason you need to use autolayout for this?